# How to get custom model attribute of element

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

How to get the model `selected-model` of this element in a protractor e2e test?

```
<div id="abc" 
     ng-dropdown-multiselect="" 
     options="dropdown.result.options"
     selected-model="dropdown.result.model" 
     extra-settings="dropdown.result.settings"
     translation-texts="dropdown.result.texts">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the model name - locate the element, for instance, using the `by.id()` locator, and then call `getAttribute()`:

```
var elm = element(by.id('abc'));
elm.getAttribute("selected-model").then(function (model) {
    console.log(model);
});
```

Or, if you want to get the model value itself, you can [`evaluate()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate) it:

```
elm.evaluate("dropdown.result.model").then(function (modelValue) {
    console.log(modelValue);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I came accross `evaluate` in the docs the second I got your response

Comment: @ShlomoGoldstein thanks, and sorry for multiple edits - I guess I should stop doing 5 things at the same time :)